# How to rename glue job output file name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I am creating a glue job where output is stored in s3 bucket. S3 path is given as follows:

```
DF.write.format('csv').mode("overwrite").save("s3://test",header='true')
```

I want a user defined file name for the output which should be appended with system date.

Ex: test20180101.csv

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
DF.write.format('csv').mode("overwrite").save("s3://test/test20180101.csv",header='true')
```

Comment: This does not work. It creates a new folder `test20180101/` and a new file `part-000-xxx.csv` inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/65631582/11842006

Don't use the partitions given in the code.

For system date you can use datetime -

```
from datetime import datetime
today = datetime.today() #will given the current date.
```

Append today in the Key of copy_object.