# AWS S3 file format

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

While writing files in S3 through Glue job, how to give custom file-name and also with timestamp format ( for example - file-name_yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm-ss) format ??

As by default, glue writes the output files in format part-0**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Glue output file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48770028/aws-glue-output-file-name)

Answer (score 0):

Since Glue is using Spark in the background it is not possible to change the file names directly.

There is the possibility to change it after you have written to S3 though. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108702/12638118) provides a simple code snippet that should work.

Comment: I tried the below code in which s3://aws-glue-test/  is bucket_name and it has part-00 files. And want to replace part-00 files to testsample.csv
But its giving exception bucket_name already exists. Can you please suggest anything which i am doing wrong? . 
attached Below code

Comment: URI = sc._gateway.jvm.java.net.URI
Path = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
FileSystem = sc._gateway.jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
fs = FileSystem.get(URI("s3://aws-glue-test/"), sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())
file_path = "s3://aws-glue-test/"
s_history.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").save(file_path)
# rename created file
created_file_path = fs.globStatus(Path(file_path + "part*.csv"))[0].getPath()
fs.rename(
    created_file_path,
    Path(file_path + "testsample.csv"))